# Aws S3 lambda upload using mobile credentials

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a mobile app that gives users credentials, using cognito.

I would like users to upload to s3 on the web, with the same user credentials.

Is this possible with lambda and api gateway? File sizes will be around 10MB.

This will be a static website hosted on s3, I have an authentication process in place, that can get their cognitoID.

Or is there another way using signed urls?

Answer (score 2):

Uploading to Lambda isn't a good idea. It has limited in payload size (up to 6mb) and also execution time (if your user is on a bad connection, it will timeout).

If you need to process something before allowing a user to upload, you can trigger Lambda, process whatever you want, generate a pre-signed S3 URL and pass it to the user, so that he can upload directly to S3.

In case you need to process something after the upload is finished, you can activate S3 streams and have a Lambda function auto-triggered any time someone uploads anything to a bucket.

Comment: Hey Renato, 

I tried and you are correct, the filesize is a limiting factor along with the timeout.

What I am doing now, is using cognito to authenticate user, then getting a presigned s3 url for that specific user as the s3 bucket has restrictions for where a user can upload, so if I am userA, I can only upload at certain prefixes.

The problem now, is that the users are authenticated using mobile SDK, and I would like to give them a presigned url, without my custom authentication, as I have a way to verify that the user on mobile is user on browser at a specific time

Comment: I was thinking about somehow generating a presigned url on mobile, encrypting it, then storing it in dynamo, in the row as the user field.

When web needs to upload, it gets the user Row, uses lambda to decrypt and then uploads file, timeout on link would be 10minutes or so, and user would need to go onto phone to regenerate the url and send another signed url.

What you think Renato?

Comment: I think it should work. When you generate the pre-signed URL and store in Dynamo, you'll be able to provide this URL to the user regardless of the device he's logged from (mobile, tablet, PC). Unless you'd expose this pre-signed URL in unsafe environments, maybe you don't really need to encrypt it. I'm assuming you're forcing all your users to connect to your app over HTTPS. In that case, all communication is already encrypted...

Comment: Good to know. I will be storing it in a Json web token, so user does not need to keep getting it from server and so I can use Zappa. Thanks for the help, Ren

Comment: It will only be a problem for you in case you're a target of a successful [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)), for example. In this case, the attacker could theoretically get the User JSON token (assuming you're storing it on LocalStorage for example) and discover the pre-signed URL. But if you're going to expose the URL at some point to the end-user (decrypted), an XSS attacker will be able to get it anyway, so, it's better invest time protecting your app as a whole instead of only the pre-signed URL... ;)

Comment: A solution for that is to store the token in dynamo, then phone user can see everything the web user is doing via sns in app, if something looks wrong the user can invalidate the token in dynamo. For the web user, periodically the request will redirect to dynamo to check the status of token from there also, maybe after every 5 requests we double check with dynamo that mobile has not invalidated token. If they have then we do not forward request and give user back an invalid token to replace the current one